# How Spring is injecting properties in Struts actions, that are not defined in applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, struts2, integration, struts

I am in a project having frameworks like Spring 3 + Struts 2 + Hibernate 3. Also it uses spring security.

Spring and Struts is integrated using spring `ContextLoaderListener` defined in `web.xml`

```xml
<listener>
    <display-name>Spring Initialization</display-name>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

There are several service classes which usually make db calls. like `agentserviceprocess` is one such class having method like `getAgents()`.

Struts actions have a property and setter getter for each process and those process classes are defined as bean in `application-context.xml`.

Surprisingly I can not find any bean having action class as class parameter. I mean spring is not controlling the action object instantiation. Then how spring can inject service property objects inside these actions?

---

Also, 
I found following entry

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Do you use spring plugin with struts?

Comment: I don't know exactly what it is. But I do some Google and found this StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter entry in web.xml. if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integration with Spring you should use [struts2-spring plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/spring/).

When this plugin is loaded the plugin's configuration is applied to use its own object factory to instantiate action classes.

When action instanses are built it passes them to Spring for autowiring.

You should provide getters and setters of properties for being autowired. You have also provide the spring configuration for dependencies.

Comment: This project does not have struts2-spring-plugin in any of pom.xml file. But still this feature is working. Not getting how.

Comment: struts2-spring-plugin should be on classpath, you can manage this artifact if you use maven in `pom.xml` to download dependencies.

Comment: Checked everything, like in deployed applications lib folder. we have 5 jars having struts* name. struts2-core-2.2.3, struts2-json-plugin-2.2.3, struts2-scope-plugin-1.0.4, struts-core-1.3.8, struts-taglib-1.3.8, struts-tiles-1.3.8 only. Is there any other configuration like any filter or listner where from I can confirm this plugin's existence ?

Comment: You should check the server log info, it would tell you if the plugin is initialized, I mean struts-spring integration.

Comment: @anirban Why do you have Struts 1 artifacts deployed?!

Comment: Ok I am trying to get that info. I deployed war in tomcat and there is no extra jar placed in tomcat/lib except db driver, so not sure where from another jar can come from, if it is not in web-app/lib?. May I ask another question related to this. Can I use AOP (aspectj / spring) on action classes methods hoping the struts-spring-plugin is in place (though I am not sure).

Comment: @DaveNewton even I am surprised to see that, why struts1 & struts2 both present there ? It might be because project is few years old and no one re factored the dependencies, just keep on adding latest ones. Which is bad.

Comment: @anirban S2 and S1 are completely different, it's not a simple matter of adding more-recent libraries.

Comment: @anirban If the struts-spring plugin is *in place* you haven't do anything more because Struts take care of injection Spring beans into the action instance. And don't use S1, that is EOL.

Comment: Thanks All for your answers. This helps.