# How to validate cookie in an struts2 interceptor

Tags: cookies, architecture, struts2, struts2-interceptors

Let me first tell you the scenario

1. I am using struts2 for my application
2. Here I want to check the validity of a particular cookie(Which has been saved if user has checked keep me logged in check box)
3. Purpose of the cookie is that if user presents a valid cookie, he will be treated as a logged in user.
4. Now I want to validate the cookie in an interceptor as this will be re used in many actions.

Problem : I have used **CookieInterceptor** provided by struts2 which is storing the cookie in the ActionContext.
**But how will I access that value in interceptor.
Or rather is it a good approach to use ActionContext values in interceptor and validate them by hitting back end services from interceptors.**

Thanx in advance.

Comment: It's possible if you know how to inject these services to the interceptor or you can get them from the invocation context. It's up to you, but IMO using helper classes to access them could be convenient inside the interceptor.

Comment: Thanx for your inputs @Roman C, but i was worried about the fact that if i want to access some ApplicationContext variable from the interceptor itself then I have to call the getter method of that variable, which will require the action to be type casted to certain type other wise I wont be able to call the getter method, and for that the Action must implement some custom interface(Which will be used for type casting while calling the getter method) thus for each such interceptor which accesses some ActionContext variable the Action need to implement some interface. Will it be a good idea?

Comment: I don't understand you, if you are getting a variable from the ApplicationContext you can easily typecast it to the type of the variable that should be the *same* type. Making the Action to implement some interface can be used to inject some variable to the action. This is not necessarily required because Struts is doing it automatically for any variable from ApplicationContext. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28477395/573032) answer.

Comment: Ya u are correct, but let me make my query very clear . From a interceptor How can I assign some value to a variable which is private to some action? Please let me know If you need some more information. This is very urgent for my requirement. Thanx in advance

Comment: Well, the variable has a private modifier, but you should provide public accessors if you want to mutate this variable from the outside.

Comment: Thanx @RomanC some how you gave me a clue. I got my answer. Thanx again. Will be looking for your future helps.